# How can one measure the exact momentum of a particle in a quantum mechanical context?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, momentum, measurements, quantum-measurements

According to quantum mechanics you can't measure both the position and momentum of a particle at the same time. A particle has an associated wave function. If you want to measure the momentum of a particle precisely, you have to make two precise measurements of position and time.

If we measure the position of one particle precisely, the wave function collapses to a sharp peak in space and is thus not the same wave function as the one you start with. A second measurement of position will thus yield a position that corresponds to the particle with the modified wave function.

So we actually need two particles with identical wave functions. You measure the position of one particle and subsequently  you measure the position of the second. That way you know the momentum of a particle with the associated particle.

But if the wave function corresponds to a sharply defined momentum it is widely spread in space. So if we make a precise first position measurement of the first particle, and after short time of the second you can get wildly varying measurements of the position differences, and thus of the momentum. Which suggests that we should use the same particle. But this has again the problem I mentioned earlier.

Or is that no problem at all? If we make a precise position measurement, the position is sharply defined and evolves by dispersing very quickly while traveling along as a (dispersive) wave function. Should we then make a second measurement very fast, so the dispersion hasn't proceeded that much? What about the extra momentum the particle got from the first mesurement?

How can we measure the momentum of a quantum particle best, assuming a Gaussian wavepacket as its wave fubction?

Comment: Why can’t you directly measure momentum?

Comment: @JonCuster momentum is mdx/dt. It needs two measurements of x (and time).

Comment: @Felicia to give a counter-example: if I want to determine the momentum of a bullet, I shoot it at a target with a known mass hanging from a rope of known length. Then I measure the maximum height of the target above the initial position. That *one* measurement allows me to calculate the momentum of the bullet using conservation of mechanical energy and conservation of momentum. (note: it is best if the bullet gets stuck in the target).

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer But you have to measure the initial height first.

Comment: No, you just measure the difference.

Comment: A quantum is an irreversible transfer of energy, momentum, angular momentum and charge. The irreversibility means that we can only do a single measurement on any one quantum. As soon as we do that quantum is gone. So, yes, we can measure the energy and momentum of a single quantum at once and we can even localize it at the location of the detector, but what we can not do is to make an ensemble of quanta that have both a well defined energy/momentum and a well defined spatial distribution at the same time. In other words, what you are trying to do is simply not supported by nature.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, If the particle have electric charge, we can measure velocity, thus momentum directly. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wien_filter

If we have perpendicular electric field and magnetic field, from the proportion of E, and B, we will have particle velocity without measuring the position along the trajectory twice.